# Is "a long way to go" the same as "you need to learn a lot"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

Today I cooked something, but the taste was not good (horrible, in fact).
When my roomy tasted it, she said

> You gotta long way to go.

I asked her what exactly it meant, she replied "You need to learn a lot".

But so far I only knew it meant "You will be successful in future".

So, can anybody tell me what exactly "A long way to go" means and where I should use this phrase?

Comment: You can look it up in the dictionary. Do a quick search, you'll find something like [this](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/a-long-way-to-go)

Comment: 'This tastes horrible' (if I might adapt your own words slightly – and, believe me, my carrot and asparagus soup was also so described on one occasion) may be true but is hardly encouraging. "You gotta long way to go." is a nicer way of putting roughly the same truth (long way) but with the offer of hope (it's going to be a long way, but you're at least travelling the right way).

Comment: Thanks @EdwinAshworth your comment is convincing and thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add, it's a path metaphor. John Lawler has a bag full of path metaphors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend is right. She meant: "Your road to success (in cooking) is long."